# How to store a counter++ from a previous "for" loop and use it again in the next loop?

Tags: c++

I am counting cars using OpenCV and an intersection function, once a car passes an intersection it adds 1 to the "line.count" as seen down below. 
But the problem is it never adds +1 to the previous loop, and it keeps o

```
struct mline {
    int  num;
    std::string name;
    int p1x;
    int p1y;
    int p2x;
    int p2y;
    int count;
    bool shoot;
};




if (it != std::end(prvResults)) {
                int ind = std::distance(prvResults.begin(), it);
                //cout << i.track_id << " " << i.obj_id << ". P1:" << std::max((int)i.x, 0) + (i.w / 2) << ". P2:" << std::max((int)i.y, 0) + (i.h / 2) <<". Prv Points: P3:" << std::max((int)prvResults[ind].x, 0) + (prvResults[ind].w / 2) << ". P4:" << std::max((int)prvResults[ind].y, 0) + (prvResults[ind].h / 2) << endl;

                for (std::vector<mline>::const_iterator j = mLines.begin(); j != mLines.end(); ++j) {
                    mline line = *j;
                    int p3x = std::max((int)i.x, 0) + (i.w / 2);
                    int p3y = std::max((int)i.y, 0) + (i.h / 2);
                    int p4x = std::max((int)prvResults[ind].x, 0) + (prvResults[ind].w / 2);
                    int p4y = std::max((int)prvResults[ind].y, 0) + (prvResults[ind].h / 2);

                    struct Point p1 = { line.p1x, line.p1y }, p2 = { line.p2x, line.p2y };
                    struct Point p3 = { p3x, p3y }, p4 = { p4x, p4y };
                    bool res = doIntersect(p1, p2, p3, p4);
                    if (res) {
                        //cout << "Intersect " << line.p1x << line.p1y << " " << line.p2x << line.p2y << endl;

                        line.count=line.count++;
                        line.shoot = true;

                        cout << " " <<line.count << " : " << line.name ;



                    }
                }
            }

std::vector<mline> load_measurement_lines(std::string filename, int scale = 1) {
    std::vector<mline> mlines;

    std::ifstream file(filename);
    std::vector<std::string> file_lines;
    if (!file.is_open()) return mlines;
    for (std::string line; getline(file, line);)
        file_lines.push_back(line);
    std::cout << "object names loaded \n";

    for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator i = file_lines.begin(); i != file_lines.end(); ++i) {
        // process i
        mline newmline = {};

        std::string mlinedetails = *i;  //0;line_0;665 521,628 524 -> mlinedetails

        size_t pos = mlinedetails.find(";");    //1
        newmline.num = std::stoi(mlinedetails.substr(0, pos));  //0
        mlinedetails.erase(0, pos + 1);                         //line_0;665 521,628 524 -> mlinedetails
        pos = mlinedetails.find(";");                           //6
        newmline.name = mlinedetails.substr(0, pos);            //line_0
        mlinedetails.erase(0, pos + 1);                         //665 521,628 524 -> mlinedetails
        pos = mlinedetails.find(",");                           //7
        std::string token = mlinedetails.substr(0, pos);        //665 521 -> token
        newmline.p1x = stoi(token.substr(0, token.find(" "))) * scale;  //665
        token.erase(0, token.find(" ") + 1);                        //521 -> token
        newmline.p1y = stoi(token) * scale;

        mlinedetails.erase(0, pos + 1);                         //628 524 -> mlinedetails
        token = mlinedetails;
        newmline.p2x = stoi(token.substr(0, token.find(" "))) * scale;  //628
        token.erase(0, token.find(" ") + 1);                        //524 -> token
        newmline.p2y = stoi(token) * scale;

        newmline.count = 0;
        mlines.push_back(newmline);
        //std::cout << newmline.num << " " << newmline.name << ";" << newmline.p1x << "," << newmline.p1y << "," << newmline.p2x << "," << newmline.p2y << "\n";
    }
    return mlines;
}
```

this is the output of the program.

[image: this is the output of the program]

As seen in the picture I expect the output to be

```
1: line 10
 2: line 10
  3: line 10
```

But the output is

```
1: line 10
 1: line 10
 1: line 10
```

It's not adding up [image]

Comment: instead of `line.count=line.count++;`, maybe you meant `line.count=line.count + 1;`

Comment: ... or just `++line.count;`.

Comment: @m.m Adding line.count=line.count + 1, made the output to be 0s instead of 1s

Comment: @Scheff still the same output, it stays 1 at all times.

Comment: `line` is a local variable of the `for` loop anyway so changing its members has no ongoing effect. To get your sample output you are going to need to increment some integer variable that's defined before the loop (so it still exists after each loop iteration).

Comment: @m.m I have line.count in another function, is there a way to reference the values to another functions?

Comment: @m.m can you check the edit version please

Comment: I don't see what the edit version has to do with the problem  .   Your code is like this (simplified to remove stuff not relevant to the problem): `for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { int x =0 ; x = x + 1;  cout << x << ": line 10\n"; }`.  Do you understand why that outputs the same thing 10 times, and how to fix it? If so, then you could apply the same understanding to your real code.

Comment: if you're asking about how to use function parameters to share values between functions then check any book or introduction to the language

Comment: Unfortunately, your question isn't ready for posting yet. In particular, it lacks a [mcve] while containing too much redundant information. Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your increment of `line.count` is just plain wrong. Lets dissect your statement

```
line.count = line.count++;
```

`line.count++` increments `line.count` and returns the **old** value. You then take this (old) value and assign it to `line.count`. So effectively you do not change `line.count`  at all. You can do either just `line.count++`, `++line.count`, or something like `line.count += 1` to properly increment `line.count` (and you may want to read about the pre- and post-increment operators in C++).

**Edit**: There also is another issue in your code: `line` is a variable **local** to the loop. Each iteration starts with

```
mline line = *j;
```

So in each iteration you create a new object `line`. Modifications to that object will of course be lost to the next iteration. Also, the modification you make to `line` will not be reflected in `*j`. I am not sure what your goal is here but I see two options to fix this:

1. Move `line` out of the loop.
2. Instead of `mline line = *j` try to use a reference `mline &line = *j` (or a pointer if references do not work, or just use `j` directly).

Comment: changed it to line.count++ and still the same output.

Comment: There is another bug in your code. I updated my answer with that. You may also want to read through the comments you got for your question. Other people have mentioned exactly that bug.